# Can we write the Ito differential dBt into some "differential form" like we do for df where f is smooth?

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

There is a standard definition that $\mathrm{d} f$ means a cotangent vector field (1-form) when $f$ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a smooth $n$-manifold $M$, by which we can make the expression
$$
\mathbb{d} f= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \mathrm{d}x_i
$$
hold mathematically and rigorously.

My question is: can we do a similar thing to $\mathrm{d} B_t$ (or $\mathrm{d} W_t$) in an Ito integral so that it is also a well-defined mathematical rigorous object, and Ito formula
$$
d X_t=\mu_t d t+\sigma_t d B_t
$$

$$
d f(X_t)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\mu_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\sigma_t^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right) d t+\sigma_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} d B_t
$$
be rigorously correct?

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is the Stratonovich differential, which obeys the normal calculus for differentials. Unlike the Brownian increment, which is the difference between the future value and the present, the Stratonovich increment is symmetric between the past and the future.

Comment: If you could do this what would be $ddB\,?$

Comment: @KurtG. I think this does not have to make sense, because after all $dB_t$ cannot be defined in the same way as exterior derivatives of differentiable functions.

Comment: I realize that I misunderstood the question. Sorry about that. I think the answer is that $dB_t$ and $dW_t$ are the simplest Ito differentials of all. You get $df(B_t)=dB_t$ when $f(x)=x\,.$